# How can i redirect user to their specific page In node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Basically I want to redirect user to their pages.

If it's a user, it should redirect to user's menu on the other hand, if it's an employee, it should redirect to employee's menu.

When I try to login, it shows logged in is `true` but, it is still on login page and throws error as shown below -

```js
Customer and employee undefined
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

**Login.js**

```js
router.post("/login", function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      console.log("email password");
      return res.redirect("/login");
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
      req.session.user = user;
      req.session.save((err) => {
        console.log(err);

        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
          if (req.session.isLoggedIn === true) {
            let customer = User.find(user.email);
            let employee = Employee.find(user.email);
            if (employee) {
              res.render("employeeMenu");
            }
            if (customer) {
              res.render("clientMenu");
            }
          }
          return res.render("index");
        }
        console.log("user not exist");
        return res.redirect("/login");
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    req.isLogged = true;
    return next();
  } else {
    req.isLogged = false;
    return next();
  }
}
```

User Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

 const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema({

   firstName:{
      type:String,
      required:true
   },
   lastName:{
      type:String,
      required:true
   },  
   email:{
      type:String,
      required:true,
      unique:true
   },
   password:{
      type:String,
      required:true,
  }
})

Users = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = Users
```

Employee Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const employeeSchema = new Schema({
   First_name:{
       type: String,
       required:true
   },
   Last_name:{
       type:String,
       required:true
   },
   email:{
       type:String,
       required:true,
       unique:true,
  },
  contactNo:{
       type:Number,
       required:true,
       unique:true
 },
 password:{
       type:String,
       required:true,
 }, 
 joined:{
    type:Date,
    default:Date.now
 }
})

Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema)
module.exports = Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to write middleware, not a route handler. So,

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user == null){
// if user is not logged-in redirect back to login page //
        res.redirect('/');
    }   else{
        next();
    }
});
```

And also as the error suggest, you haven't created the `customer and employee` **fields or columns** in your database schema.
Hence, create it.

Comment: i already write the middle-ware, that's why it show user logged in true and create session key. I just want to do redirect to specific page

Comment: Yeah! I aplogize. I didn't read the question details properly.

Comment: @usmanimtiaz Can you show database schema model as the error is related to what's in database schema fields ?

Comment: it's okay. i just want to redirect the user according to their mail like if it's an employee i should redirect to employee menu if it's an customer it should redirect to user's menu

Comment: i update the question now u can see the models, but their is not any error in model it show error on let customer and employee in login route

Comment: try replacing above `let customer = User.find(user.email); let employee = Employee.find(user.email);` with `let customer = User.find({ email: user.email });  let employee = Employee.find({ email: user.email });`

Comment: @usmanimtiaz Not just the above changes for the `employee and customer` but do correct the syntax for `passport.authenticate` which is 
`app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }));` 
as per the [passport documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/)

Comment: i try     let customer = User.find({ email: user.email });  let employee = Employee.find({ email: user.email }); but still same issue

Comment: Try updating `passport.authenticate("local", function (err, user, info) {})`  **to** `passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }, function (err, user, info) {})`.